# WinUI 3 runtime localization

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3

I am developing WinUI 3 app, currently stuck with localization. Although I wrote separate resw resource files for different cultures and localized with `x:Uid` I cannot find a way to change language in app runtime.

Setting `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` only works fine for settings startup language.

Is runtime localization in WinUI 3 even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

I think you're on the right track. If you are trying to change the language at runtime, call a method that will set `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` to the new language "string". But then after that, you will also have to [reload your Page so that the new language takes effect](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/guides/hotswap-app-language.html?tabs=tabid-vswin).

```
private void ReloadLanguage(string languageOverride)
{
    // Change the app language
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = languageOverride;

    // Be sure to clear the Frame stack so that cached Pages are removed, otherwise they will have the old language.
    Frame.BackStack.Clear();

    // Reload the page that you want to have the new language
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

}
```

-OR-

You'll have to [call your ResourceLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#updating-strings-in-response-to-qualifier-value-change-events) for the UI components you need/want to refresh one at a time.

```
private void RefreshUIText()
{
    var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
    this.myXAMLTextBlockElement.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("Farewell");
}
```

**Updated Answer:**

According to [Microsoft online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#updating-strings-in-response-to-qualifier-value-change-events), they suggest that anytime you change the language for you "to reload your strings from the default **ResourceContext**".  I know this is not ideal, but it appears to work.

I got the following Example Solution below to work:

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

***MainPage.xaml***

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Greeting" x:Name="Greeting" Text="" Margin="15"/>
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Farewell" x:Name="Farewell" Text="" Margin="15"/>
        <Button x:Name="SelectLanguageButton" Click="SelectLanguageButton_Click" Content="Select Language" Margin="15"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

***MainPage.xaml.cs***

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshUIText();
    }

    private void SelectLanguageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(LanguagePage));
    }

    private void RefreshUIText()
    {
        var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse();
        this.Greeting.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("Greeting/Text");
        this.Farewell.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("Farewell/Text");
    }
}
```

***LanguagePage.xaml***

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="EnglishButton" Click="EnglishButton_Click" Content="English" Margin="15"/>
        <Button x:Name="FrenchButton" Click="FrenchButton_Click" Content="French" Margin="15"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

***LanguagePage.xaml.cs***

```
public sealed partial class LanguagePage : Page
{
    public LanguagePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EnglishButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReloadLanguage("en");
    }

    private void FrenchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReloadLanguage("fr");
    }

    private void ReloadLanguage(string languageOverride)
    {
        // Change the app language
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = languageOverride;

        // Be sure to clear the Frame stack so that cached Pages are removed, otherwise they will have the old language.
        Frame.BackStack.Clear();

        // Reload the page that you want to have the new language
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

***Resource Files and contents, Solution Explorer***

[image]

***Also remember to add your language declarations in the Package.appxmanifest file***

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately suggested doesn't work with Win32 (desktop) app model.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is it? Also, showing some code could help get you closer to a solution if we could see what you've implemented thus far.

Comment: Thank you, your updated answer makes sense.
Note that Refresh method could also be written as below:

private void RefreshUIText(string lang)
{
   var context = new ResourceContext(); // deliberately not using getForCurrentView()
   context.Languages = new List<string>() { lang };
   ResourceMap resourceMap=ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");
   String str = resourceMap.GetValue("LanguageSettings_Title/Text", context).ValueAsString;
   this.BackBtn.Content = str;
}

Comment: To anyone coming here: this works to localize your own strings, but strings that are already part of controls - like the `Settings Button` on a  `NavigationView` don't get updated. Restarting the app seems to be the only way for those to work so far

Answer (score 1):

I've spent many hours on this subject. Here's my sincere advice: **DO NOT TRY TO LOCALIZE YOUR VIEWS**. Also, don't try to handle changes to the language at RunTime. No one does this, you'll never see an ROI in the investment.

Make all your localization in the view models and use the StringLocalizer class that's built into .NET's DI. Add the string localizer to the DI first:

```
this.serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddLocalization();
```

Then, in your .NET or .Net Standard library, in your view model, add the following initialization:

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<LandingViewModel> stringLocalizer;

public MyViewModel(IStringLocalizer<MyViewModel> stringLocalizer)
{
    this.stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;
}
```

Now, if you have some text you want to display, say on a button, you'd have:

```
public string SignUpText => this.stringLocalizer["SignUp"];
```

And in XAML, you'd have:

```
        <Button Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.SignUpText}"/>
```

Finally, give the RESX file the same name as your view model. It should be an Embedded Resource with, and this is important, no custom tool:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a NuGet package called **WinUI3Localizer** that helps you with localization.

GitHub:
https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/WinUI3Localizer

- No app restart
- You/users can edit localized strings even after deployment
- You/users can add new languages even after deployment
- Uses standard "Resources.resw"

Answer (score 0):

I created new project - **Blank App, Packaged with WAP(WinUI 3 in Desktop)** with latest project templates, which come with VS extension **Windows APP SDK C# VS2019**. As you noticed - I am using VS 2019, Community edition. I am attaching csproj configuration of a project below.

[image: Project config]

There is a frame in main window which navigates to main page. There is only one button on main page which leads to LanguagePage on click.

[image: Main window ctr]

Goal is to change language, clear navigation stack and navigate back to main page. However, various scenarios in `SetAppLanguage` didn't produced wanted result.
[image]

Please take a look at https://www.py4u.net/discuss/731870 - tried all scenarios, no effect on GUI.
Nevertheless `Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();` is throwing a COMException: 'Resource Contexts may not be created on threads that do not have a CoreWindow. (0x80073B27)'

Comment: I tried all scenarios as you did and can confirm that there is no effect on the GUI. It only works if you close/restart the app. I think this is because of the cache, but even steps to reset the ResourceContext doesn't seem to work. However I was able to get it to work (although not ideal). Please see the updates that I gave to my answer.